# how can i let the user to only copy the TextEdit's text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TextEdit in my form, and i only want to let the user to copy it's containt and not to edit it , if i use the `TextEdit.Enabled = false;` i can't copy the TextEdit's containt.

Please, how can i let the user to only copy the text.

Comment: Just hook the changed event and set `e.Handled = true;` or something like that.

Comment: thanks I tried TextEdit.Properties.ReadOnly = true; it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `TextEdit.Properties.ReadOnly = true`. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `ReadOnly` to true, and add a button in the form to copy the text, and write this code in the `button1_Click` event handler:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
```